# Javascript - functional approach to remove empty elements from end of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

The input array is the following:

```
var arr = ["some", "", "", "value", "", "", ""];
```

I need to remove the empty elements from the tail. So the expected output is:

```
["some", "", "", "value"]
```

I know a boring reverse loop would work, or pop() until it comes to the first non-empty element. E.g.:

```
while(arr.pop() === "")
```

However, just for fun i would love to see an equally or more efficient (if possible) **functional** approach.

My first functional idea was implementing it with **reverse** -> **reduce** -> **reverse**. However it seems to complex, so i wanted to see if somebody has a better approach.

```
var arr = ["some", "", "", "value", "", "", ""];

var result = arr.reverse()
    .reduce(function (a, b) {
        if (b != "")
            a.addallnext = true;

        if (a.addallnext === true)
            a.result.push(b);

        return a;
    }, {
        addallnext: false, result: []
    }).result.reverse();
```

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fy4cuspq/1/

Preferably i would love the algorithm to use built-in array methods, but if you have some amazing custom method or similar to add to the prototype, that would be great.

**Note**: My goal is not to substitute a more efficient iterative approach with a less efficient functional approach etc... it's just an exploration of functional beauty ;)

Comment: So you want to take an `O(n)` algorithm (looping backwards or popping until you get a not empty result) and replace it with a `O(3n)` algorithm (reverse, reduce, reverse)?

Comment: Of course not. As i said, it's just for fun ;) exploring functional approaches.

Comment: @MattBurland Both algorithms are O(n).

Comment: @JLRishe: Correct, I misspoke. Actually, if you consider best case performance, looping backwards is `O(1)` (no empty elements), while reverse, reduce, reverse would still be `O(n)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `reduceRight`. I'm using `Array.prototype.concat` to keep code free of mutations. Also, I rely on the length of the result to see when to stop removing empty strings.

```
var reducedArray = arr.reduceRight(function (result, a) {
  return result.length === 0 && a === ""
       ? result
       : [a].concat(result);
}, []);
```

Comment: I somehow forgot about reduceRight :) this is a good approach. Thanks!

Comment: My mind just exploded here. Can you explain it line by line? Looks very interesting (I'm struggled on the return, lol)

Comment: @briosheje it's pretty simple actually. The reduceRight processes the elements from right to left (reverse order). The result variable is initialized as [ ] in the reduceRight function, and the callback should always return it no matter what. However, if the elements on the right are empty, they will not be added to the result (that's why he is returning the result only, without prepending the current element -a-), and if a is not empty, it will be prepended to the result [ ] using concat ;) with the prepending approach, he prevented having to reverse() the array again ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about simply removing the last element as long as it's an empty string ?

```
var arr = ["some", "", "", "value", "", "", ""];

while ( arr.getLast() == "" )  arr.pop();
```

(EDIT: OP just edited the question saying that he doesn't want this particular method.. )

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the OP put in their question?

Comment: Look at the edit history, it was there from the start: `I know a boring reverse loop would work, or pop() until it comes to the first non-empty element`

Comment: didn't see it .. oh well

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a more efficient one that **@Ionut** although his looks prettier.

[**perf**](http://jsperf.com/reduceright-vs-some) (*22%*)
  | [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2vyyh84x/)

```
arr.reverse();
arr.some(function(elem, i, array) {
  if (elem) {
    array.splice(0, i);
    return true;
  } else return false;
});
arr.reverse();
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Is that an implicit global? Jeepers!

Comment: @JLRishe No it's not, you didn't see ANYTHING.

Answer (score 1):

The problem boils down to finding the length of the initial subarray which does not end with the empty string. Since Javascript's Array.prototype.reduce is kind enough to provide the current index into the array, this can be achieved with a simple `reduce`:

```
function trim(arr) { 
  return arr.slice(0,arr.reduce(function(i,b,j){return b===""?i:j+1},0))
}
```

In the `reduce`, the first argument at each point is the length of the current trimmed segment. Since the third argument is the current *index*, it needs to be incremented to produce the current *length*.

If `reduce` didn't provide the extra arguments to the callback, you could do it (still functionally, but less legibly) by passing a pair of values through the reduction:

```
function trim(arr) { 
  return arr.slice(0,arr.reduce(
      function(ij,b){
          return [b===""?ij[0]:ij[1]+1,
                  [ij[1]+1]
      },[0,0])[0])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there will be some complications with stringfy and parse, but here's my one liner with Regex:

```
var arr = ["some", "", "", "value", "", "", ""];
var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/(,"")+]$/,"]"))
```